# Checking ISBN numbers

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def isISBN(n):
    if len(n)!= 10:
        return False
    else:
        d1=int(n[0])*1
        d2=int(n[1])*2
        d3=int(n[2])*3
        d4=int(n[3])*4
        d5=int(n[4])*5
        d6=int(n[5])*6
        d7=int(n[6])*7
        d8=int(n[7])*8
        d9=int(n[8])*9
    d10=(d1+d2+d3+d4+d5+d6+d7+d8+d9)
    num=d10%11
    print(d10,num)
    if num==10:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Here are some test cases my teacher gave us:

```
>>> isISBN('020103803X')
True
>>> isISBN('0540122068')
True
>>> isISBN('020108303X')
False
>>> isISBN('0540122069')
False
```

The code fails the test `'0540122068'` because my output is `False`, but I don't know why.

Comment: what's your logic...what qualifies a good ISBN number?

Comment: Why some of you cases contains characters? As far as I am aware the `ISBN 10` does not contain characters (?) but correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Write a python function 'isISBN(n)' that takes a string of 10 characters and tests whether n is a valid ISBN. You can assume that the string has 10 characters, you do not need to check that:

Comment: this is the question!

Comment: i am not sure how to do this question,

Comment: Hi @YingweiFan, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @YingweiFan, have a study on something called Regular Expressions. I'm sure there's one for the pattern, but you must first identify what the pattern is. Make a conjecture, if its a string of 10 digits then that's a pretty straightforward regex.

Comment: @jxramos this is not a task for a regex.

Comment: For your sum, instead of creating a new variable for each multiple of `int(n[whatever])`, do this: `sum((int(n[i]) * (i + 1)) for i in range(9))`.

Comment: @Rishav interesting, never knew the rules for ISBN, particularly the check digit part. Cool stuff

Comment: @Rafael ISBN numbers sometimes include `X` as the number is base 11 (even though only digits 0-9 are used.) Sometimes the checksum is 10, so we use `X`.

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks for pointing that out. In my answer below I have included the `X` case, which make sense for representing the number `10`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the 10th value and check for modulo equivalence to 0:

```
def isISBN(n):
    if len(n)!= 10:
        return False
    else:
        d1=int(n[0])*1
        d2=int(n[1])*2
        d3=int(n[2])*3
        d4=int(n[3])*4
        d5=int(n[4])*5
        d6=int(n[5])*6
        d7=int(n[6])*7
        d8=int(n[7])*8
        d9=int(n[8])*9
        if n[9] == 'X':
            d10 = 10
        else:
            d10 = int(n[9])
        d10 = d10*10
        d11=(d1+d2+d3+d4+d5+d6+d7+d8+d9+d10)
        num=d11%11
        if num==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

isISBN("3680087837")
```

Comment: And now you can write a more elegant version, maybe ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#ISBN-10_check_digit_calculation) there is a mathematical way to calculate the correctness of an `ISBN`.

Moreover [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit#ISBN_10) is another brief description of the algorithm:

> The final character of a ten digit International Standard Book Number
>   is a check digit computed so that multiplying each digit by its
>   position in the number (counting from the right) and taking the sum of
>   these products modulo 11 is 0. The digit the farthest to the right
>   (which is multiplied by 1) is the check digit, chosen to make the sum
>   correct. It may need to have the value 10, which is represented as the
>   letter X. For example, take the ISBN 0-201-53082-1: The sum of
>   products is 0×10 + 2×9 + 0×8 + 1×7 + 5×6 + 3×5 + 0×4 + 8×3 + 2×2 + 1×1
>   = 99 ≡ 0 (mod 11). So the ISBN is valid. Note that positions can also be counted from left, in which case the check digit is multiplied by
>   10, to check validity: 0×1 + 2×2 + 0×3 + 1×4 + 5×5 + 3×6 + 0×7 + 8×8 +
>   2×9 + 1×10 = 143 ≡ 0 (mod 11).

The algorithm is the following:

1. From each digit of your ISBN starting from left, you multiple *each* by an incremental number, starting from `1`. That is the first digit multiply by `1`, the second multiple with `2`, up to digit `10` multiple by `10`.
2. You then sum up those multiplications.
3. You perform a modulo operation on the above summation with the number `11` (That is `sum % 11`)
4. If the modulo operation return back `0` then the given `ISBN` is valid, if anything else, then is not.

As you can see from the above reference, your mistakes are the following:

1. You don't multiplying the 10th digit by 10.
2. An `ISBN` is valid if the modulo operation returns `0` and not `10` as you wrote.

Note:

As the above reference state, you could have the last digit as `X` as you can't have the `10` as a number in your `ISBN`. In that case you would like to check if the 10th digit is an `X` to use the `10` number instead like that:

```
d10 = 10*10 if n[9] == "X" else n[9]*10
```